# Creating distinct pages for author profiles and lists of posts by author

Tags: author, profiles, author-template

The site I'm currently working on includes profile pages for each author plus a method to search for posts by a specific author. So we would have a page at `/author/author-name/` that only displays a list of posts by that author and a page at something like `/author/author-name/profile/` that shows extended user info but no posts.

By default Wordpress includes an `author.php` template that shows some basic user info and recent posts by the author. This is found at `/author/author-name/`. When looking for recommended ways to build a user profile, everything I have found recommends altering this file and using the same URL, however we would like to use both.

The only way I can think of achieving this would be to allow the page to take a parameter so that `/author/author-name/?profile=1`, rewrite it in `.htaccess` so that it appears as `/author/author-name/profile/`. Then alter `author.php` to check for this parameter and use a separate template. I would like to avoid methods such as this and stay on the Wordpress rails as much as possible.

Are there any plugins or other Wordpress approved methods I could use to solve this problem? (We're running 3.8 by the way).

Comment: WordPress features a [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) that allows you to create endpoints, etc, without needing to customize your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: If you got an answer, please don't add it to the question. Add it as answer. Brings upvotes and using Q/A to share knowledge and answer your own questions is fully ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) with `EP_AUTHORS` target. That should take care of URLs and query var to check for [relatively :)] cleanly.

Comment: And use a GET parameter as I described to show different content?

Comment: @Godwin read the linked docs please, endpoint will provide a query var to check for.

Comment: Thanks, took a while to completely understand. I'm going to update my question to make it easier for others that are not familiar with `add_rewrite_endpoint`.

Comment: @Godwin sorry if answer was too short, it was late night for me :) Could you please move your solution to an answer? That is more in line with site's mechanics than adding it as part of question.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Rarst's answer, in case you're not familiar with `add_rewrite_endpoint`, here's what I came up with.

Create a template file named `author-profile.php`. In your `functions.php` file add the following:

```
add_action('init', 'theme_add_author_profile_endpoint');
add_action('template_redirect', 'theme_author_profile_template_redirect');

function theme_add_author_archive_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('profile', EP_AUTHORS);
}

function theme_author_archive_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['profile']) && is_author()) {
        include dirname( __FILE__ ).'/author-profile.php';
        exit;
    }
}
```

This should allow `/author/author-name/` to be directed to the default `author.php` template while `/author/author-name/profile/` will be directed to `author-profile.php`.